# New class (added on branch) not included in DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity

I've got a class library that contains a class called TestService. I added it using Visual Studio's "Add -> Class" menu. In the csproj file, it looks fine

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Compile Include="Implementation\TestService.cs" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

I can't find any 'Exclude' statements anywhere, and it all builds fine in Visual Studio. However during an MS Build operation (on TeamCity), when I look in the resulting DLL using dotPeek, my class isn't there (and my build fails).

The class was added on a branch, and is merged into the trunk during the build. The merged .csproj file looks good.

I have tried with the default namespace (chosen by VS2010, matches the folder structure) which is "**TimetablingPhase2.Service.Implementation**". All the other classes in the same folder have the namespace "**TimetablingPhase2.Service**, which I have also tried (another developer wrote this code originally).

Can anyone suggest why it's not being included in my DLL? Below is a screenshot of the added class.

[image: Screenshot of solution]

Thanks

Comment: 99% of the time when I something like this, I'd say you're looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, not sure where else to look really. I've checked all the solution files, csproj files, deleted the class, re-added it, deleted all the TeamCity cache etc, changed the namespaces as a sanity check etc etc. Not sure where to turn now!

Comment: Wierd, I just added a new class (Test.cs) in the same namespace and it's now building the other classes too...

Comment: did you check the namespace of ActivityLogService.cs ? @Richard

Comment: Hi @Rezoan, its namespace is consistent with all the other classes that are in the same folder. I'm wondering if it's something to do with the build actions and/or build configurations but I can't see anything obvious yet

Comment: can you please show us the class structure. im'n not the body part. also please show us a screen shot of your soln explorer in expand view.

Comment: Hi, I have created a completely new branch to keep things simple. The only difference between the branch and the trunk is that the branch has a new class (TestService.cs) and its interface (ITestService.cs) - see screenshot. I get exactly the same problem i.e. TestService is not in the DLL when TeamCity builds it, even though it's mentioned in the .csproj file. Thanks for your help

Comment: If I add the class to the trunk first (as an experiment) it includes it in the DLL. If I edit an existing class on the branch, the changes are included in the DLL. It just seems to be ignoring **new** classes that were added on the branch.

Comment: Could it be because of this (taken from the build log):  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files

Comment: I think I'm very close actually. I tracked down the csc.exe command that TeamCity/MSBuild is executing, and it doesn't list my new classes as ones that need to be compiled, even though they are listed in the csproj file. So the question is, where is TeamCity getting that list from. Could it be building it up *before* the merge has taken place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix: I swapped the order of my build tasks around. Instead of the order being:

1) Clean.
2) Merge.
3) Compile.

I now do:

1) Merge.
2) Clean.
3) Compile.

Happy to be corrected on this, but I think this is the reason:

1. The list of classes to compile is loaded into MSBuild when the first
   build target (Clean) is executed.
2. Then I merged the code, which changed the list of classes to compile (added extra classes).
3. But because that list had already been loaded, my new classes
   (which by then **were** listed in the csproj file) were never picked
   up.
4. Doing the Merge first makes sure the list is up-to-date before
   MSBuild reads it.